# Can bash reverse history search (Crtl+R) be configured to NOT delete history?

Tags: bash

I find Ctrl+R very useful,

however I am really anoyed that when I press the backspace key, 
it deletes the currently matched entry in the history.

Is there a way to disable this ?

Comment: It seems to be the way that history works. The same is true if you use the cursor up/down keys to traverse the history. If you edit the current history command and execute the result, a new entry is added and the previous entry is preserved. If you edit the entry and don't want to execute the result, then press **Ctrl-C** *without moving to another history line* and the previous entry is also preserved. As soon as you edit a history line and then move to another line, the update is committed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this setting to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
set revert-all-at-newline on
```